# How to implement this SOQL query?

Tags: soql

I have three tables:
Contact, Relationships, and RelationshipReports

Contact is one-to-many with Relationships, Relationships is one-to-many with RelationshipReports

I'm interested in getting records from Contact that have any records in RelationshipReports.  I've tried doing a SOQL query with 2 nested IN statements and have gotten an error.

Coming off from SQL world and having issues grasping at simplest SF concepts I guess.

Appreciate any help!

Comment: It will be easier to help you if you could post your query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Apex, you can traverse 5 levels from child to Parent, but unfortunately when going from Parent to Child, you can only go 1 level.  From your description it sounds like you are trying to traverse down, not up.  So you need to attack this from the bottom-up (Grandchild up to the Grandparent).

This was baffling to me when I first made started learning SOQL

Try something like this

```
Select Relationship__r.Contact__r.Name from RelationshipReports__c GROUP BY (Relationship__r.Contact__r.Name)
```

Check out this documentation as well.  Should help

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/dbcom_soql_sosl/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships.htm

Comment: I've got the query to run, I needed to pre-pend the RelationshipReports__c to all of the field names I needed to retrieve.  Thanks!  Now, I have a new dilemma - one of the fields was not group-able, so I had to use "MAX" function and rename the field.  However, now the resulting data is not serializingng through SOAP API to the entity that I'm expecting

Comment: I can't think of a solution off the top of my head, but I would add it as another question so people will see it, as it will get lost in this comment and people will not see it.